# minus a set of some constant values from a set of values of a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

there is a table like id- name-roll
i have some set of constant given value of roll like-
(1,2,6,8,5) let it be set A
table has roll like(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) let it be set B
i want to know A-B
means those values of roll which is not in the table but exist in the given constant set A

i tried
select roll from "tablename" where roll not in(1,2,6,8,5);
but it return just opposite-
it return B-A
but i want A-B
please help
i also tried

select (1,2,6,8,5) from dual minus select roll from tablename;
but it gives some syntex error

Comment: Your question is very hard to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(select 1 as id from dual
         union all
select 2 from dual
         union all
select 6 from dual
         union all
select 8 from dual
         union all
select 5 from dual
         )
minus
Select id from b
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.*
from (select 1 as id from dual union all
      select 2 as id from dual union all
      select 6 as id from dual union all
      select 8 as id from dual union all
      select 5 as id from dual
     ) a
where not exists (select 1 from b where a.id = b.id);
```